# How to convert f32 to String with dynamic precision?

Tags: rust

In my rust code I have a function which takes a float and precision as args. The function should return the formatted string. However, I am not sure how I can format with dynamic precision,

```
fn convert(val: f32, precision: i16) -> String {
    format!("{:.2}", val) // The 2 should be replaced with precision
}
// convert(1.2345, 1) -> 1.2
// convert(1.2345, 2) -> 1.23
```

Comment: Use the [precision formatting](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/fmt/index.html#precision) syntax.

Comment: I would say this is not a duplicate because I was not able to find the dynamic precision. I saw that answer but it is not answering mine

Comment: @Selva there are two answers to that question. The less-voted one is what you want.

Comment: Ah... Right. I missed it. Thanks for pointing it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to [the documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fmt/index.html#precision):

> There are three possible ways to specify the desired precision:
>
> 1. An integer `.N`:
>
>    the integer `N` itself is the precision.
> 2. An integer or name followed by dollar sign `.N$`:
>
>    use format argument `N` (which must be a `usize`) as the precision.
> 3. An asterisk `.*`:
>
>    `.*` means that this `{...}` is associated with two format inputs rather than one: the first input holds the `usize` precision, and the second holds the value to print. Note that in this case, if one uses the format string `{<arg>:<spec>.*}`, then the `<arg>` part refers to the value to print, and the precision must come in the input preceding `<arg>`.

That is, you can use:

```rust
fn convert(val: f32, precision: usize) -> String {
    format!("{:.prec$}", val, prec = precision)
}

fn main() {
    println!("{}", convert(3.14, 0));
    println!("{}", convert(3.14, 1));
    println!("{}", convert(3.14, 2));
    println!("{}", convert(3.14, 3));
}
```

([Permalink to the playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=ae3861b6f41ea6aab937a07a0b660449))

Comment: I looked into the document but didn't find it. May be it was not easy to identify